# Nvidia 361.42 and LightDM problem on xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, login, lightdm, nvidia-prime

I am using xubuntu 16.04 with intel and nvidia GPUs. When using intel there are no problems, when doing `prime-select nvidia` and logging out lightdm will not start with the error message (see below). The screen is black with ***_*** sign stays on it. I can switch to text console, but no X.

If I will use XDM as a login manager there will be no issue and a session using nvidia drivers.

If I do `prime select intel` every thing goes back to normal.

How to fix?

```
** Message: Starting lightdm-gtk-greeter 2.0.1 (Apr 11 2016, 06:05:31)
** Message: [Configuration] Reading file: /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d/01_ubuntu.conf
** Message: [Configuration] Reading file: /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d/30_xubuntu.conf
** Message: [Configuration] Reading file: /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf

** (process:3499): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'

(lightdm-gtk-greeter:3171): Gdk-WARNING **: lightdm-gtk-greeter: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have done a "fresh install" of xubuntu 16.04 and not knowing the model of the machine and neither the video card i would do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings.
```

Then running nvidia-settings i would figure out what my needs are and make the settings permanent.

Comment: I'm on XPS 15 9550. Nvidia is 960M. I'll give it a try and will post later. Thanks